# read words from one file and remove the containing lines from another file

Tags: python

I want to write a script that read each line of *file1* which is a string of words, **search** it inside *file2*, and the lines of *file2* which doesn't contain the words, are written into a new file. Example:

file1

```
good
bad
```

file2

```
Hi,
I am a bad man
Trying to be a good one.
Bye.
```

Result(file3)

```
Hi
Bye.
```

This is my attempt:

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f1:
    for line1 in f1:
        f1_line = line1.rstrip()

        with open("file2.txt") as f2:
            for line2 in f2:
                f2_line = line2.rstrip()

                if f1_line not in f2_line:
                    with open("file3.txt", 'a') as f3:
                        f3.write(f2_line + '\n')
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the result is too far off.

My logic is: I read the first line of file1, then I open each lines of file2. If the file1_line is not inside the file2_lines, then I write the file2_line inside a new file, and continue with the next word.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Have you tried to debug your code to find out where it's going wrong? If not, I suggest that you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice All of the file2 contents are written into the new file. None of them are being removed.

Comment: You shouldn't use nested loops. Read everything from file1 into a list. Then read each line of file2, check if it contains any of the words in the list, and write it into file3 if not.

Comment: There's no real reason to not use nested loops, although it *might* be faster to only read the word file `f1` once, instead of reading the whole thing over-and-over again for each line in `f2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, read the search words into a list.

```
with open("file1.txt") as f1:
    wordslist = [line.strip() for line in f1]
```

Now, `wordslist` is `['good', 'bad']`

Then, read file2 line-by-line, and check if the line contains [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) words you read into `wordslist`:

```
with open("file2.txt") as f2, open("file3.txt", "w") as f3:
    for line in f2:
        if not any(word in line for word in wordslist):
            f3.write(line)
```

file3 now contains:

```
Hi,
Bye.
```

Comment: For the OP: Notice how Pranav described what he is doing **in words**. I'm willing to bet he did this first before writing any code. This is almost always the first step in writing any computer program.

Answer (score 5):

You could do by taking advantage of the optional `else` clause that `for` statement's have (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)) which will be executed if a `break` statement is **not** executed during iterations of the body of the loop. This makes it easy to determine if any words from the first file were found (without using a "found" flag or something similar).

```
with open("file2.txt", 'r') as f2, open("file3.txt", 'w') as f3:
    for line2 in f2:
        f2_line = line2.rstrip()

        with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f1:
            for line1 in f1:
                f1_line = line1.rstrip()
                if f1_line in f2_line:
                    break
            else:  # None found.
                f3.write(f2_line + '\n')

print('fini')
```